# UHF RFID. Телефоны

Tags: android, авторизация, terminal

Прочел в интернете, а причем [тут](https://serialio.com/products/scanner/mobile/Android/Android_Faces.php), что на телефонах с ОС Андроид(2.3 или выше) поддерживается сканирование RFID меток. Является ли это истиной ? :D. 
Спрошу вот так: Есть телефоны в которых есть RFID считыватель.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В статье по вашей ссылке речь идет о конкретных моделях внешних считывателей RFID-меток, которые взаимодействуют со смартфоном через Bluetooth и Wi-Fi.

> *Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. BLE support for idChamp RS3, Scanfob® NFC-BB2-BLE and more (Android 4.3+ needed for BLE support)

Однако, телефон оснащенный NFC-модулем может считывать некоторые RFID-метки диапазона **HF** (13.56 МГц, стандарт ISO 14443).

**UHF** RFID метки работают на совершенно других частотах (860—960 МГц). Их вам считать НЕ удастся.